# Wget windows and multiple --header switches

Tags: json, http-headers, wget

I'm trying to use wget 1.11.4 running on Windows Server 2003 to do some JSON with a web site. I can retrieve info OK but I can't send any. I'm not positive that my JSON is formatted correctly but there seems to be a more fundamental problem.

If I do:

```
wget --header="Authorization: Bearer <redacted>" --no-check-certificate --post-data="{'workspaces':{'title':'CMC Regulatory Support','creator_role':'maven'}}"  https://api.mavenlink.com/api/v1/workspaces.json
```

I get a JSON error back from the site "ERROR 422: Unprocessable Entity." But if I add another --header:

```
wget -S --header="Authorization: Bearer <redacted>" -–header="Content-Type: application/json" --no-check-certificate --post-data="{'workspaces':{'title':'CMC Regulatory Support','creator_role':'maven'}}"  https://api.mavenlink.com/api/v1/workspaces.json
```

I get:

```
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = C:\Program Files\GnuWin32/etc/wgetrc
wget: invalid option -- û
Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...

Try `wget --help' for more options.
```

but the manual clearly states that multiple --header switches are allowed, and I see that swithc used in examples on the web?. WTF?

Answer (score 7):

Your second `--header` parameter before the `Content-Type` contains different dashes.

`-–header="Content-Type`

If you fix it wget will send the request.